# Postgresql pgagent Job scheduler insert data error

Tags: postgresql, pgagent

I'm only new in using `postgresql` and I'm having a hard time to make my scheduled job works.
I already tested the `pgagent` if there's any problem. I already created a sample job that connects to postgres database. I also created a sample table in public schema named `emp`, the job successfully insert a data when I run it but after I created a new database in `localhost` named `sample_accounts` with `acc` schema and `acc_active` table on it, the job which I connected to `sample_accounts db` won't insert any data to the `acc.acc_active` table Below are my screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Did I miss anything in here sirs? I hope someone can help me. Thank you

Comment: Without an error message, it's hard to tell what went wrong. Did you check the logfiles? And why do you need pgAgent? It might have it's purposes, but after 20 years of database usage, I could have used it maybe once or twice but ended with a different/better solution using external job schedulers like cron.

Comment: Hi the log says, `could not receive data from client: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.`